# Why can't set bin log for MariaDB in Debian 9?

Tags: logging, mariadb, debian-stretch, bin

It is simple to set bin log for mysql in centos,just uncomment the line in `/etc/my.cnf`.
Before uncomment in my.cnf.

```
#log_bin  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

Uncomment it in my.cnf.

```
log_bin  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

No `/etc/my.cnf` in debian9's mariadb.
1.Add log_bin directory in debian9's `mysql.cnf`.

```
sudo vim  /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
log_bin  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sudo touch /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sudo chown mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log    
sudo systemctl restart  mysql
sudo systemctl status  mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-05-02 08:16:54 CST; 24s ago
```

It seems no issue for the setting.

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql: unknown variable 'log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log'
```

2.Add log_bin directory in debian9's `50-server.cnf`.

```
sudo vim  /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
log_bin  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

Now to restart mysql.

```
sudo systemctl restart  mysql
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

What's happening?

```
sudo journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has finished shutting down.
May 02 08:32:26 debian systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
May 02 08:32:27 debian mysqld[3640]: 2019-05-02  8:32:27 140494098832768 [Note] 
May 02 08:32:30 debian systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=ex
May 02 08:32:30 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
```

How to set bin log for Maradb in debian9?

Comment: Check if binary logs are enabled or not, to enable or disable do below.
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;

Comment: The config file contains multiple sections. Make sure you put the `log_bin=` line in the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: It is under [mysqld] section, i am sure.

Comment: Check MariaDB's own logs for the error that was logged.

Answer (score 0):

Test many times on my pc.

`sudo apt install mariadb-client mariadb-server` can enable bin log,with the same process ,`sudo apt install mariadb-server` can't enable bin log ,although `sudo apt install mariadb-server` shall trigger the os install `mariadb-client`,i don't know why.